# File to array in python

Tags: python, arrays, file

I'm reading a tutorial about python for very beginners and at some point the author define some ways to work with files. My doubt is related to memory management and file arrays.

```
#open a file for reading
file = open(filename, 'r')
#this turns the file into an array. 
lines = file.readlines() `
```

Python is smart enough to check the file size? What happens if the file has about 1 GB of data? Python will throw the entire file to the memory (array)? Or this is a *lazy operation*, just like C/C++ does!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the tutorial use `file` as a variable name?

Comment: Yes. I know this isn't a good way to define a variable name because `file` is a type-object in python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting the [Python Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects):

> To read a file’s contents, call `f.read(size)`, which reads some quantity of data and returns it as a string. `size` is an optional numeric argument. When size is omitted or negative, the entire contents of the file will be read and returned; **it’s your problem if the file is twice as large as your machine’s memory.** Otherwise, at most size bytes are read and returned. If the end of the file has been reached, `f.read()` will return an empty string (`""`).

It also applies for `readlines()`, so Python will "throw" the entire file to the memory.

Also, by quoting [Python Docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.readlines):

> **`file.readlines([sizehint]):`** Read until EOF using readline() and return a list containing the lines thus read. ...

Answer (score 0):

**`Python is smart enough to check the file size?`**

Yes. There are some OS related function. You can get file size using them.

**`What happens if the file has about 1 GB of data?
Python will throw the entire file to the memory (array)?
Or this is a lazy operation, just like C/C++ does!`**

If you use `fp.readlines`, yes 1GB of data will be stored in memory.
But unsurprisingly there is a such function which increase file pointer like C/C++. So you can read data chunk by chunk and reduce memory usage.

`fp.read(n)`

I think this is the C/C++ like file operation you are saying.